# REGEXP_COUNT ignoring case sensitivity

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Hello I am trying to implement a some simple oracle queries, and i was testing the usage of regexp_count.

I ran into this weird case, the code:

```
select regexp_count('OOO', '[a-z0-9]', 1,'c') from dual;
```

This returns 3 (1 match per character), when it should return 0. It seems that it is ignoring the flag 'c' (case sensitivity), and matching the 'O' as an 'o'.

[image]

Is this the intended behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: This works in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=326b654593c4f87ee673a43aceb4bb4b.

Comment: are you sure that your pattern is **not** `'[a-zA-Z0-9]'` , or the value contains **three zeroes** instead of the three letters "O" ..? (it's working properly)

Comment: what on earth it must be a missconfiguration with my oracle, I am using 12.2.0.1.0 not sure if it matters @GordonLinoff

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that is the exact qeury, it must be some missconfiguration on my oracle

Comment: What locale are you using, and what is NLS_SORT set to in your session? The 'c' match parameter should probably make that irrelevant, but still... You can possibly avoid the issue by using `'[[:lower:]0-9]'`, or `'[[:lower:][:digit:]]'`, and might not need the 'c' in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  parameter IN ( 'NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT' );
```

And see what NLS session parameters you are using.

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY;
SELECT regexp_count('OOO', '[a-z0-9]', 1, 'c' ) AS COUNT_AZ,
       regexp_count('OOO', '[[:lower:][:digit:]]', 1, 'c' ) AS count_lower
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COUNT_AZ | COUNT_LOWER
> -------: | ----------:
>        0 |           0
> ```

But:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=ANSI;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=GERMAN_AI;
-- or ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=GERMAN_CI;
-- or ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=FRENCH_CI;
-- or many others
SELECT regexp_count('OOO', '[a-z0-9]', 1, 'c' ) AS COUNT_AZ,
       regexp_count('OOO', '[[:lower:][:digit:]]', 1, 'c' ) AS count_lower
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COUNT_AZ | COUNT_LOWER
> -------: | ----------:
>        3 |           0
> ```

To fix this, you can either:

- Change the `NLS_SORT` session parameter.
- Or (as mentioned by @AlexPoole) use the `[:lower:]` POSIX character-set instead of `a-z`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5dc31ad650105854b5025390b350197)*

Comment: Thanks, my NLS_SORT was Western_European, changing it to BINARY solved it! Much appreciated